# Change actionbar spinner theme

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with the following theme: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. As a result, the **actionbar title** and the **"more" options menu item** are all white, as I would expect:

[image]

But, as you can see from the screenshot, the drop down menu has a black background. I would like the drop down menu to have a grayish background (see screenshot below).

I have noticed that the style of the drop down menu is related to the general style of the activity, for example if the activity style is changed to: `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, then it will look now like this:

[image]

which is exactly the kind of style I am looking for, but as you might have noticed, the actionbar title and the "more" options are now black, which given the kind of theme makes sense but is no longer what I need.

Now, I know there are a couple of ways to deal with this situation: the first one would be not to use the navigation mode list at all because it is deprecated already, another would be to use a `Toolbar` and have a `Spinner` within it, both styled. But before going this route, I want to make sure maybe there's an easier approach.

I tried to have a custom theme that extends from the `Theme.AppCompat.Light`:

```
 <style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and then use it to create a themed context when inflating the drop down menu:

```
Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.LightTheme);
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(context);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, null);
```

but this unfortunately had no effect.

So, is there a way the style of the drop down menu can be changed without affecting other components, eg.: the actionbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always theme the toolbar properties within your `style.xml` of you application. I would recommend using a no action bar style where within your toolbar you can style the spinner but since you are not using it you can just directly style it in your theme.

For spinner style you can add this in your main app theme or specific:

`<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
 <item name="spinnerStyle">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>`

For popup style:

`<item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.